# XCode 7.3 - Workspace usage

Tags: xcode, swift, project, workspace, xcode7.3

I have been trying to understand xcode..

What is a Workspace? 
Is there something that can't be done with a project that needs a Workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a page explaining [what Workspace is](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html).

In short, it's used to group several projects together to build an app. If you use CocoaPods for example, the pods are referenced as targets from another project. A workspace helps tie your code and those pods together to make an app.

Comment: For what i know, a project can be referenced from another project and used there. What I understood from the link is that Workspace facilitates the workflow in some cases. Is that it?

Comment: Not understanding "Workspace the workflow"

Answer (score 0):

You use a workspace to share a code library amongst multiple projects.

Watch https://youtu.be/LNU6L2pnq0k and it should help you get a better idea of why/how they are used.